# Does using FP16 help accelerate generation? (HuggingFace BART)

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, seq2seq

I follow the guide below to use FP16 in PyTorch.
https://pytorch.org/blog/accelerating-training-on-nvidia-gpus-with-pytorch-automatic-mixed-precision/

Basically, I'm using BART in HuggingFace for generation

1. During the training phase, I'm able to get 2x speedup and less GPU memory consumption

But.

1. I found out there is no speedup when I call `model.generate` under `torch.cuda.amp.autocast()`.

```py
with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
   model.generate(...)
```

2. When I save the model by:

```py
model.save_pretrained("model_folder")
```

the size does not decrease to half. But I have to call `model.half()` before saving in order to make the model half size.

Thus, my questions:

- Is the issue in `1.` expected or there should be something I did wrong?
- Is the operation I did in `2.` proper?